# What's the concise notation for "option values"?

Tags: functional-programming

Is there a mathematical symbol or otherwise concise notation to represent option values (OCaml's `option` type, Haskell's `Maybe`...)?

It appears so often in functional programming that I would expect to find a concise syntax for this type, the same way lists have a somewhat standard `[]` notation, functions have the `->` notation, and so on.

I know that in a more formal context one might use a partial function notation , but in most cases it doesn't fit as nicely as some explicit symbols for Some/None (or Just/Nothing).

Ideally, I'd like to write something like:

`This function returns #42 if the input is valid, @ otherwise.`

Where `#42` represents `Some 42` and `@` represents `None`, but in a standard way, easily understandable by most readers (or at least those with some mathematical background).

Comment: Well, if you need to ask whether there is any such notation, there clearly isn't one that's easily understandable by **any** reader. ;P

Comment: You're right, I reformulated it to consider "readers with some mathematical background", which I may be lacking.
Maybe there's some language where null/non-null references share some sort of similar notation? I considered using question marks "?", but they are used in regexes and so, I'm not sure they'd be a right notation.

Comment: For the question mark: There exists a notation like [`int?`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) in C#, which translates to `Nullable<int>`, but that's quite specific (only for value types), and doesn't show up at the value level (you can just write `1` or `null`, not `#1`).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen any such specific notation. The closest I know is to use of mathematical symbols to express the type: `α ⊕ 1`. Here ⊕ represents direct sum (disjoint union) of types and 1 represents the unit type.

This notation is used in category theory or in typing systems.